# How can I manually convert an ASP.NET MVC 2 application to MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Does anybody know the minimum steps that are required to be done in order to convert an MVC 2 (.NET 4) application to MVC 3?

I tried the upgrade tool, but it gives errors for my solution.

Comment: Is MVC 3 officially released or is it still a release candidate?

Comment: Could you email me the conversion log and solution, project, and web.config files of the project that causes the converter to fail? Email is [my user name]@microsoft.com

Comment: @marchind no problem http://awesome.codeplex.com/releases/view/59082#DownloadId=197268

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in the upgrade tool when a solution had solution items or web sites. The bug has been fixed and an updated version of the tool is available on codeplex: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008.

More information on my blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx